# need help with regex helicon rule

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, iis

I need some help with the regex as i am writing a new rule in the helicon.

the sample url will have file name and a query string parameter i want to match on both

```
www.testwebsite.com/hello.aspx?filename=/test.asp&employeeid=2100&age=20
```

in the above url i want to check if it is hello.aspx and has query string `filename=/test.asp`

filename can be anywhere in the querystring.

i want to break the above url into some other page

```
mynewpage.aspx $2$3 etc///
```

i wrote the following url but its not working , it matching pattern for all like sample1.aspx or any file name

```
(.*)(\/hello.aspx\?+)(.*)(filename=\/test\.asp)(.*)
```

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

What you need are [non capturing groups](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet):

```
(?:.*)(\/hello.aspx\?+)(?:.*)(filename=\/test\.asp)(?:.*)
["www.testwebsite.com/hello.aspx?filename=/test.asp&employeeid=2100&age=20", "/hello.aspx?", "filename=/test.asp"]

(?:.*)(\/hello.aspx\?+)(?:.*)(filename=\/test\.asp)(.*)
["www.testwebsite.com/hello.aspx?filename=/test.asp&employeeid=2100&age=20", "/hello.aspx?", "filename=/test.asp", "&employeeid=2100&age=20"]
```

If you want to get all the [parameters separately from the query string](http://dnohr.dk/aspnet/how-to-get-url-querystring-variables-from-a-string-url-with-csharp) you can do it like this:

```
string queryString = (new Uri("...")).Query;
NameValueCollection parameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);
parameters.Get("filename");
parameters.Get("employeeid");
parameters.Get("age");
```

Comment: @dan i am not getting all the query string values.in $3

Comment: @i need employeeid and age also.

Comment: oh, sorry, I forgot about that

Comment: do the filename, employee id and age show up in this order always ?

Comment: could you specify what exactly do you expect to capture in group $3 ?

Comment: all remaining..querystring values.

Comment: If by that you mean `$3="&employeeid=2100&age=20"` than simply make the last group capturing again. If you however expect that $2 is the first param, $3 is the second, $4 is the third, and so on without knowing the total number beforehand, than that's not possible with just regex.

Comment: i just want all remaining query string values...thats it.